# array and object confusion in json

Tags: javascript, json

what is the different between is

```
var json = [{
'id':1,
'name':'John'
}]
```

and

```
var json = {
'id':1,
'name':'John'
}
```

my understanding is that in code one json is an array, which means we can have multiple object which contains property of id and name. But for the second one it's an object. Is it?

and how about this one

```
var json = ['id':1,'name':'John']
```

compare to code one?

Comment: Yes you are correct, the first one is an array that contains an object. The second one is an object. the last one is not valid JS/JSON. But this is all Javascript not JSON

Comment: Nothing in the question is JSON. The first is an [*Array initialiser*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.1.4) or array literal, the second is an [*Object initialiser*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.1.4) or object literal. JSON is text that uses javascript literal notation to represent objects and arrays and that can be exchanged between systems.

Answer (score 3):

### Nothing is valid JSON in your case.

The first one is an `array` of native javascript objects.

The second one is a javascript object.

The last one isn't valid and will throw error. It is syntactically wrong.

Use `JSON.stringify()` on javascript arrays or objects to make it a valid JSON.

Comment: the first one isn't a json? what is a json then? I'm more confused now.

Comment: @noob, `[{"id":1,"name":"John"}]` is a valid json of your first code. Read more at http://json.org

Comment: @noob JSON is a way of representing Javascript data as a string, so it can be saved in a file or transmitted over the network.

Comment: @noob JSON uses a subset of Javascript literal syntax as the notation.

Answer (score 2):

You understanding about code one and code two are correct. 
But however, the json syntax about code one and two is error. Because each json field must use **double quotes**, not **single quotes**.
so code one and code two must be written like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "John"
    }
]
```

and

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "John"
}
```

Now code three's syntax is error! If you want to mean an array, it must be `var json = []; json['id']=1; json['name']='John';` or an object `var json={'id':1,'name':John'}`

Answer (score 1):

JSON is a format, i.e. a way to encode Javascript objects to a sequence of characters.

Once you have a sequence of characters you can store it on disk or send it over a network and later rebuild the objects described in the sequence of characters.

You cannot encode every possible Javascript value in JSON, but only

- strings
- numbers (excluding NaN and infinity)
- null
- arrays
- other objects (just the fields with values that can be encoded, not the constructor or methods)

Also, the data structure must be a tree. (You get an error if it has loops, and shared sub-trees are not detected and will be duplicated when rebuilding from JSON.)

Moreover JSON doesn't support is the presence of other fields in arrays (something that is possible in Javascript, because arrays are objects). For JSON, you have either an array or an object.

The values in your first two examples can be converted to JSON, but there are additional requirements in the format specifications. (E.g. object field names must be double quoted.)

Your last example instead is not a valid JSON string.

When you see "JSON object" or "JSON value" you must read it as "object encoded in JSON". JSON is a format, more or less like XML.